# Credit card detection while editing the input number itself (like pre guess)(after typing 4 digits) in Java?

Tags: java, android, regex, credit-card

There are many examples exist for validating full number but Could anybody help me how can I start for pre-guessing Credit Card validation while typing the number itself digit by digit (at least after entering 4 digit), not a full complete number in Java?

PS: Question is not duplicate, Full number validation answers exist but my requirement is after entering 4 digits. Thanks

Comment: CC validation is not validated digit by digit

Comment: The Luhn algorithm requires the full CC number

Comment: I mean, sure you could do it, but there's no point in running a validation on a number shorter than 15 digits

Comment: Thanks, @cricket_007,  But my project requirement says after entering 4 digits at least I should be able to get card type?

Comment: Guys, The question is not duplicate, My question is after editing 4 digits not full number, anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dbachelder/CreditCardEntry](https://github.com/dbachelder/CreditCardEntry) and [vinaygaba/CreditCardView](https://github.com/vinaygaba/CreditCardView) and [sharish/CreditCardView](https://github.com/sharish/CreditCardView) on github have pretty good implementations to follow.

[dbachelder/CreditCardEntry](https://github.com/dbachelder/CreditCardEntry/blob/master/CreditCardEntry/src/com/devmarvel/creditcardentry/library/CardType.java) is one of the examples of how to implement some of the regex needed to pre-guess the card type. Just remember to validate the full-card number with luhn algorithm before accepting it. [FreeFormatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/credit-card-number-generator-validator.html) site has some good information on how to validate a credit card number. In any case, the card has to be validated with a payment processor before you can be certain that it is a valid card number.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks a lot :) That what I needed to look into! I don't understand y ppl are downvoting my question.

Comment: The downvotes are probably due to the fact that, a simple github/stackoverflow search would have saved you a ton of time in typing this question. But I think it would have been a good idea to let you know that this is just a simple search

Comment: Thanks, Maybe Anyways I am new to Android and Java!

Comment: @Neelam  Personally, I downvoted because you asked us to "help you with the logic", yet included no logic in the question for anyone to help you with

Comment: @cricket_007: Thanks Appreciated, will take care in future! anyways updated the question!